# A manga about the adventure of a pair of brother and sister in a game world

Tags: .hack

Around 1-3 years ago, I found an interesting manga in my local library, but I didn't bring my library card with me. The following week, I returned to borrow it to read, but of course it was gone :/

Things I remember is:

- The manga was based in a game world or VR.
- They were not trapped like SAO, rather it was a really good VR.
- There was a boy and girl, and they were brother and sister.
- The brother complained about his sister's lewd or ecchi outfit, and it was a running gag where he challenged people who hit on her.

The story content included:

- Finding a phoenix down to save someone
- A cute hippo-like pet, which could be grown into a mount. (One of the side/main characters had one of these, and he was kinda an arsehole)
- There was a race and people was swimming in it

It has been translated into English, because it's in my local library and I live in the UK.

Answer (score 10):

I believe you are looking for [***.hack//Legend of the Twilight***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.hack//Legend_of_the_Twilight).

- It's about a game called *The World*.
- People can freely log out, including the main characters.
- The main characters are a boy named Shugo and his twin sister Rena.
- Rena's outfit is quite revealing.
- There are hippo-like creatures, called *Piikey*. Hotaru, one of the female side characters, has one as a pet. Komiyan the Third, one of the male side character, uses one as a mount. Both main characters find Komiyan annoying.
- The Phoenix Down (aka Phoenix Feather) is used to save the life of Hotaru's Piikey.
- One of the GMs (Game Masters) loves to organize events. One of those, I faintly remember being a race involving swimming.

Comment: I should note however that not all players could freely log out, players killed by certain monsters were stuck in the game while they real world bodies were in comas (though this was in the anime version. i am unsure about the manga version)

Comment: @Memor-X. It happens in the manga too, but I think the problem lies with the players being in a coma rather than artificially kept from logging out, also I chose not to mention it, since it's a bit of a spoiler.